# SQL Distinct on First Column OpenQuery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, progress-4gl, openquery, progress-db

I'm using an `OpenQuery` in SQL Server 2014 to retrieve data from Progress.

This is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(PRG, 'SELECT "cde","dsc" FROM tblCodes')
```

And it retrieves data like this:

```
cde     dsc
===     =====
one     test
one     another
one     value
two     goes
two     here
two     also
three   example
```

However, I need to have results look like this:

```
cde     dsc
===     =====
one     test
two     goes
three   example
```

How do I do this in an `OpenQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your open query your query should be like below and I recommend you to have the cde column as a numeric ID :

```
 WITH CTE AS (select cde,dsc,
    row_number() over(
                        partition by cde
                        order by cde
                    ) as rn

from tblCodes 
)
select cde,dsc from CTE 
where rn =1
```

Check the execution here : [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f2bec/6)

Comment: this works.  FYI: The cde is a string field, not numeric